# find out which control triggered postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I have aspx website in which I have multiple user controls. I want to know which control (button, dropdown, radiobutton) triggered postback from those user controls. 
How I can do that. 
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From:
http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx

```
string ctrlname = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != string.Empty)
{
    return this.Page.FindControl(ctrlname);
}
```